# Sending sms from blackberry simulator is possible?

Tags: java-me, sms, blackberry-simulator

Is it possible to send sms messages from blackberry simulator to other mobile devices..
Because i have written a code for that but am unable to send so any one can help me in that and even let me know whether it is possible to send messages to other mobiles ?

Answer (score 1):

No, its not possible.

Reason: Simulator/Emulator doesn't have SIM Card, and without that you can't send SMS. You may send Message through GPRS if you use any third party API like `WaytoSMS`

Comment: thanks for the answer,,it is very helpful for me ...and i have another doudt i.e then how to run two blackberry simulators at on pc and send sms to each other..am using eclipse so can you help me to solve this problem

Comment: Yes, it is possible, when you run your simulator, it gives a number like 50001 , use this number to send sms from another simulator,

Comment: thankzz...my problem is solved...i solved it by creating two workspaces in eclipse and launched two different simulators..Now am able to send sms messages

Answer (score 0):

I think it is quite possible - Why shouldn't it be?
You can use any given Telecom API (there are plenty out there), and use a Java lib to have your BB simulator send and receive SMSs.
I'm involved in a project right now which allows you to do just that.